# How to removed wrapped <article>-tag?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I want to remove all EMPTY article tags that are wrapped in my code, e.g.:

```
 <article>
 </article>
```

But it should also work for:

```
 <article></article>
```

and

```
 <article> </article>
```

I have this at the moment (in my WordPress theme's function.php) but it won't work:

```
function remove_empty_articles($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('#<article>(.+)</article>#', '', $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_empty_articles');
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this pattern instead:

```
#<article>\s*</article>#
```

with `\s*` that means zero or more white characters. The capture group is not needed.

The pattern you used was false for two reasons:

- the dot `.` matches any characters except newlines (this will delete all one line article tags and not find article tags that are on several lines.)
- the + quantifier means 1 or more times, you can find `<article></article>` with it.

Comment: Nice, gotcha! Will check it as soon as the 5 minutes are over!